# cv2.floodFill() hanging with certain inputs

Tags: python, opencv

I have a loop to run through an image and do a flood fill every 20 pixels:

```
h, w = image.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((h+2, w+2), np.uint8)
mask[:] |= 0
flags = 4
flags |= cv2.FLOODFILL_FIXED_RANGE
for x in range(20,image.shape[1]-20):
    for y in range(20,image.shape[0]-20):
        if x%20 == 0 and y%20 == 0:
            print x, y
            flooded = image.copy()
            print 'starting flood fill'
            minVal = min(image.item(x,y,0),image.item(x,y,1),image.item(x,y,2))
            maxVal = max(image.item(x,y,0),image.item(x,y,1),image.item(x,y,2))
            size = cv2.floodFill(flooded,mask,(x,y),(0,)*3, (40,)*3, (40,)*3, flags)[0]
```

Though at some points cv2.floodFill() never completes. If I lower the lo and hi bounds it is able to process further but will sometimes still get stuck. Has anyone else had this problem?

With this image it hangs at pixel (40,400):
[image: /Users/Justin/Downloads/images/2015-07-25-12-53-17-img1.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should re-initialize `mask` inside your loops as each time `floodFill` is modifying it. Also you can improve the performance by dropping the `%` operators. And fix a bug, `image.item(x,y,`, it should be `image.item(y,x,`.

```
for x in range(20,image.shape[1]-20, 20):
    for y in range(20,image.shape[0]-20, 20):
        print x, y
        mask[:] = 0
        flooded = image.copy()
        print 'starting flood fill'
        size = cv2.floodFill(flooded,mask,(x,y),(0,)*3, (40,)*3, (40,)*3, flags)[0]
```

Comment: I'm getting the same hanging issue, and I am not doing it in a for loop like the OP. It's hanging if the lo and hi bounds are too large numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I found the actual cause of your hanging.

It turns out that the lo and hi bounds must not cause the sampled color at the target point to exceed 254.

```
target_point = (25, 50)
size = cv2.floodFill(flooded,mask, target_point,(0,)*3, (40,)*3, (40,)*3, flags)[0]
```

If the values at (25,50) is 253, then the max for lo and hi bound is 1.

I fixed it with this code that just checks to make sure the bounds will not cause the value to go over 254.

```
val = img_f.item(target_point[1], target_point[0])
bounds = min(254-val, INSERT_LO_HI_BOUND_HERE)
```